# Java Mail API setContent() not written in the mail body as HTML

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I need to add some HTML contents into mail body. this is what i have tried so far.

```
            message.setContent(
                      "<h1>You Have a Promotion</h1>",
                     "text/html");

            message.setContent(
                      "<h3>Your First Name :</h3>" + FirstNm,
                     "text/html");

            message.setContent(
                      "<h3>Your Last Name :</h3>" + LastNm,
                     "text/html");

            message.setContent(
                      "<h5>Your Employee ID :</h5>" + Employeeid,
                     "text/html");
```

If i get the Out put only the last field display in the body of mail which is Employee ID. i want to display all three fields in the Body of the mail.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not common with the functionality you use but here is what I'm seeing. You are setting the "content" of the message several times so each time it replaces the old value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set the content of the method only once if it is invoked multiple times it will override the previous values.

Try this :-

```
message.setContent(
                      "<h1>You Have a Promotion</h1> <h3>Your First Name :</h3>" + FirstNm + 
                      "<h3>Your Last Name :</h3>" + LastNm + "<h5>Your Employee ID :</h5>" + Employeeid ,
                     "text/html");
```

Below is code for setting text in case of multipart message

```
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                // Fill the message
                messageBodyPart.setContent("<h1>You Have a Promotion</h1> <h3>Your First Name :</h3>" + FirstNm + 
                          "<h3>Your Last Name :</h3>" + LastNm + "<h5>Your Employee ID :</h5>" + Employeeid ,"text/html");
                // Create a multipar message
                Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                // Set text message part
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

                // Part two is attachment
                messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource("");//add file path
                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                messageBodyPart.setFileName("");//file name to be displayed
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                message.setContent(multipart);
```

Comment: I would use a `StringBuilder` for content concatenation, but otherwise this is the answer.

Comment: but problem i facing here is h have to attach a file from a directory too. so  that how can i call all the above elements and the multipart from the setContent().

Comment: Sir, in your edition eclipse says The method setText(String) in the type Part is not applicable for the arguments (String, String).

Comment: I have edited my answer test it as currently i don't have environment to test

Comment: Instead of setText use setContent of messageBodyPart i think it will solve the issue.I have edited the answer